# How to repair a slow leak in sink food disposal, at discharge

Tags: garbage-disposal

It is a slow leak, perhaps less than a cup a day, so I have time to plan. That is good, because plumbing is not really my thing.

I would like to repair rather than replace, to save money.

Should I try to tighten down on the bolt that I see at the site of the leak, or undo the bold and replace the black washer/gasket that seems to be failing.

What is the name of the washer/gasket piece that I likely will need to replace?

Is this type of part standard and easy to find or should I go to the mfg website: https://insinkerator.emerson.com/  I did not find the part on that site.

Mfg: Emerson insinkerator 
Model 17-85
SIN 05111658797

If there is good reason to replace the whole disposal rather than repair it, let me know.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.
[image: front view]
[image: side view]
[image: mfg label]

Comment: A disposal has no water source, so the amount of leakage depends entirely on how often you are draining your sink (or possibly dishwasher).   But since you can see where the leak is,  follow the answers and replace gaskets, clean all mating surfaces, etc. --- or replace if the mating surface is corroded beyond usability

Answer (score 2):

This is a fairly easy repair to make. You didn't say if it's working but I'm assuming it is and it's not jammed. First unplug the disposal. You could have a blockage in there so make sure that there isn't standing water in the disposal.  It's possible that the screw is just loose but I would put a bucket under the disposal and remove the top screw over the tailpipe coming out of the disposal and remove the tailpipe. You'll see a rubber gasket that seals that connection to the tailpiece. I think you'll at least have to replace that gasket. 
Once it's open you'll have a better idea of what's going on. It's obviously corroded. Clean it out as best you can. If everything else looks okay take the gasket along with the pictures that you posted here along to your local home center. They should have that rubber gasket.

Comment: I would prefer ordering the gasket online rather than go out in putblic these days. Does the rubber gasket have a name or part number?

Comment: This link should take you to the part on the HD website.https://images.homedepot-static.com/productImages/f076206f-d727-4aae-94a6-b411ca80bfd0/svn/mixed-finishes-danco-garbage-disposal-parts-88002-64_400_compressed.jpg

Comment: Here's the product link at HD. https://www.homedepot.com/p/DANCO-InSinkErator-Disposal-Repair-Kit-88002/203193989

Answer (score 1):

There is an awful lot of corrosion where the down pipe connects to the disposal. Remove the nut on top and remove the retaining bracket. Loosen the brass nut at the end of the pipe and swivel the pipe out of the way. Now examine the disposal to determine if the recessed area of the disposal is rusted beyond repair or if cleaning it out and getting a new rubber seal will stop the leak. You can get one at a plumbing supply store. The bracket fits into a groove on the bottom and is secured on top by the screw. If that groove or recessed area is disintegrated, stopping the leak will be almost impossible. In my experience, when the corrosion is that bad, replacing the disposal is your best bet.

Comment: I would prefer ordering the gasket online rather than go out in putblic these days. Does the rubber gasket have a name or part number?

Comment: @Yehuda_NYC        https://www.culinarydepotinc.com/insinkerator-75499-coupler-flex?utm_source=google&utm_medium=ppc&utm_campaign={SmartBelow200Shop}&gclid=CjwKCAjwvOHzBRBoEiwA48i6Aply42KLTjBoPF-tAorWLH-5e3bckMbaywh7Yjb4xfCzNkI5R4MrpRoCzAUQAvD_BwE

Comment: The part you link to looks different from the one posted in another answer: https://www.homedepot.com/p/DANCO-InSinkErator-Disposal-Repair-Kit-88002/203193989. Can either be used or should I use the one which looks closest to the leaking gasket?

Comment: The item I listed was a universal Insinkerator part that accommodated different pipe entries. You  would just cut off what you didn't need.  The part  @HoneyDo  lists is the actual part for your disposal and would be a better fit . Think about getting a new unit before taking this one part... if your unit can be fixed, just return the new one to HD.  If it can't be fixed, you'll have the new one available.

Comment: The model I have has been discontinued.  Is there an easy way to find out if another model has connections in the same places and is roughly the same size?

Comment: Most disposals have connections pretty much in the same place and same brands usually have the same mounting bracket for easy change outs.  Check, Google, Home Depot or in-sink-erator  for a 3'4 horsepower disposal. and look for one that's similar to yours.

Comment: See follow-on question: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/187286/how-to-move-these-disposal-discharge-connections

Answer (score 1):

It has been my experience that when a disposer body is made of die cast aluminum corrosion of the type showing in your picture  means that the metal has been eaten away over time. When it gets to the state showing it is highly unlikely that it will be  repairable with just a new gasket/retainer.

One point I would like to make is that now might not be a good time to take it apart to "take a look at it". If you did disassemble it there would be next to no chance that you could put it back together with the same parts and achieve the current low leak rate. I suggest just putting a bucket under it for now until you can get a new unit.

Comment: Well, the disposal came with a 5 year guarantee and it was part of the house when we bought it 10 years ago, so probably the disposal does need to be replaced.  (But I'll try a repair anyway.)

Comment: See follow-on question: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/187286/how-to-move-these-disposal-discharge-connections