# How to move these disposal discharge connections?

Tags: garbage-disposal, fitting

I will need to replace my 10+ year old garbage disposal ([How to repair a slow leak in sink food disposal, at discharge](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/187199/how-to-repair-a-slow-leak-in-sink-food-disposal-at-discharge/187202?noredirect=1#comment330192_187202)).  The mfg help line says the model 17 I have is obsolete and the replacement is the InSinkErator 76944, Cover Control Plus Garbage Disposal
But the recommended replacement is 2.5" wider and 2" taller than the old one.

The existing discharge piping seems very sturdy but may be hard to reuse because there is NOT enough room for the new larger model without relocating that sturdy piping.  (See photos below.)

What might be the easiest (or best) way for me to modify the existing piping to accommodate the new, larger disposal? Should I try to use/reuse the 2" metal disposal piping, by moving or modifying it as needed, or replace it with 2" flexible discharge tube like this: https://www.lowes.com/pd/InSinkErator-Flexible-Discharge-Tube-2-in-White-Plastic-Garbage-Disposal-Discharge-Tube/1269327

Will connecting new plastic tube into the wall be easy, since there is a threaded connection (it seems from the first photo), or is that threaded connection likely to be hard to remove since it is old and so close to the wall?  In any case, what is the name of the adapter I need to connect the 2" plastic discharge tube to the 2" threaded connection in the wall?

How much of a U shape is needed in the discharge and could that U be made of flexible tubing?

Any tips would be greatly appreciated. (Plumbing is not my thing.)

[image: threaded_at_wall]
[image: middle+of_pipe_run]
[image: at_disposal]

Comment: Does the new disposer sit ok alongside the existing horizontal section of the drain pipe?

Comment: The mfg help desk said the openings were not in exactly the same place, but close.

Comment: My question was regards to the fit of the new one next to the horizontal section going into the wall.

Comment: @MichaelKaras. I fond a diagram of the new model on the web, but the exact location is still not clear to me. Why do you ask?

Comment: I ask because there is an outside chance that you may not need to remove the piece that goes into the wall. You can get some fit adjustment for the down spout from the disposer to the P-trap by rotating the disposer some and the where the lower section of the P-trap is swung. If the new disposer is close to similar to the old one that may be just enough adjustment. Unfortunately you do not have the luxury of one other common adjustment at the wall. It is common to also have a slip nut fitting at the wall that permit an additional adjustment vector by letting (continued)

Comment: (continued from above) that horizontal pipe slide in and out of the wall pipe some. Sadly you have a hard threaded and soldered connection there.

Answer (score 1):

OK, If you have to remove the copper piping, start with the trap, the "u" thing, which you need to re install with the new piping. Turn the two brass nuts counterclockwise to remove them from the down pipe and the main drain. The threaded fitting  at the wall should be able to be removed by turning it counterclockwise with a 12 or 14" pipe wrench. The problem is you might not be able to turn it unless you cut the pipe in half, between the 90 and 45 degree bends. It will depend on the clearances. If you can modify this to make it work, it would be to your advantage. Even try calling your appliance person and see about the size of a 1/2 HP disposal. 
This will be tricky if you're not a plumbing person.

Comment: Do I have to try to hold the fitting that is protruding from the wall. while I unscrew the copper pipe?  If the pipe does not turn easily, should I heat the end up a bit to soften the old putty?

Comment: Always good to hold a fitting in place with a wrench when you're removing another fitting. You don't want it to turn or break off in the wall. Also, JACK's comment above about possibly getting a smaller 1/2 hp disposal is worth considering. It might be a lot easier to install.

Comment: I'd try without holding it first because there's not a lot of room back in there and not much to hold on to anyway.  If it doesn't turn, then a little heat but be careful because there's not a lot of room back there. If it still won't turn, then get another wrench and hold on to it.